# Freecodecamp Lern Typography by Building a Nutrition label. STEP 43

Tags: html, css

Step 43
After your last .divider element, create a p element and give it the text Total Fat 8g 10%. Wrap Total Fat in a span element with the class set to bold. Wrap 10% in another span element with the class set to bold. Finally, nest the Total Fat span element and the text 8g in an additional span element for alignment.

```
<div class="daily-value small-text">
  <p class="bold right">% Daily Value *</p>
  <div class="divider">
  </div>
  <p><span class="bold">Total Fat</span>8g<span class="bold right">10%</span></p>
</div>
```

Test
Sorry, your code does not pass. Keep trying.

Hint
Your p element should have three span elements.

Comment: your question is not clear, please read [ask] and create [mre]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the step 43 in the course you are doing might be different from the step 43 done by other users.

The below is the correct code (the above ones are basically correct but they are missing one space). To pass this step, you need to make sure to **put a space before the '8g'** so it looks like this:

```html
<div class="daily-value small-text">
  <p class="bold right">% Daily Value *</p>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <p>
      <span>
        <span class="bold">Total Fat</span> 8g
      </span>
      <span class="bold">10%</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cholesterol0mg0%

That's all you need.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdQP3.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<div class="daily-value small-text">
  <p class="bold right">% Daily Value *</p>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <p><span><span class="bold">Total Fat</span> 8g</span> <span class="bold">10%</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need three span elements with proper alignment to make this work here is a working example:

```
<div class="daily-value small-text">
  <p class="bold right">% Daily Value *</p>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <p>
      <span>
        <span class="bold">Total Fat</span>8g
      </span>
      <span class="bold">10%</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Buddy, Try the Following, Hope this Helps!

```
    <p class="bold right">% Daily Value *</p>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <p> <span><span class="bold">Total Fat</span> 8g</span> <span class="bold">10%</span></p>
 <p class="indent"> Saturated Fat 1g <span class="bold">5%</span></p>
</div>

</div>

</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="divider></div>
      <p><span><span class="bold">Total Fat</span> 8g</span> <span class="bold">10%</span></p>
      <p class="indent no-divider">Saturated Fat 1g <span class="bold">5%</span></p>
  <div class="divider"></div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following this one but  **put a space before the '8g'**:

```
<div class="divider"></div>
  <p><span><span class="bold">Total Fat</span> 8g</span> <span class="bold">10%</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="daily-value small-text">
  <p class="bold right">% Daily Value *</p>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <p><span><span class="bold">Total Fat </span> 8g</span> <span 
  class="bold">10%</span></p>
</div>
```

The questions are confusing. Please read the question again. Wrap "Total Fat" in span. The "8g" is not wrapped.Then you can nest the span around "Total Fat".

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="daily-value small-text">
      <p class="bold right">% Daily Value *</p>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <p><span><span class="bold">Total Fat</span> 8g</span> <span class="bold">10%</span></p>`enter code here`
    </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

```
<div class="daily-value small-text">
  <p class="bold right">% Daily Value *</p>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <p><span><span class="bold">Total Fat</span><span> 8g</span><span class="bold">10%</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Not quite, you've got an extra `<span>`